# Express a quotient of polynomials as a continued fraction

Tags: polynomials, fractions

I have two polinomials P(x) and Q(x), with the degree of P larger than the degree of Q, both polynomials with known real coefficients. Is there a method to express P/Q as a continued fraction of x?

Comment: The same as if they were integers, just divide $P=QA_1+R_1$. Then $\frac{P}{Q}=A_1+\frac{R_1}{Q}=A_1+\frac{1}{Q/R_1}$ and keep dividing the new improper fraction $Q/R_1$.

Comment: It usually helps to give a specific example, even when you want a general result.

Comment: It may help to reverse the process. Start with a small continued fraction and evaluate it as the quotient of polynomials. Then you can see how to reverse that to get back the continued fraction. Compare with the Euclidean algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

You have the division algorithm in polynomials, so:

$$p(x)=q(x)d_1(x)+r_1(x)\tag{1}$$ for some $d_1(x),r_1(x)$ with $\deg r_1(x)<\deg q(x).$

Then divide both sides of (1) by $q(x)$ and you get:

$$\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}=d_1(x)+\frac{r_1(x)}{q(x)}=d_1(x)+\dfrac1{\frac{q(x)}{r_1(x)}}$$

Now continue by applying the same process to $\frac{q(x)}{r_1(x)}.$ So we have:

$$q(x)=r_1(x)d_2(x)+r_2(x): \deg r_2<\deg r_1\\
\frac{q(x)}{r_1(x)} = d_2(x)+\dfrac1{\frac{r_1(x)}{r_2(x)}}$$

Keep doing this until the remainder $r_n(x)=0,$ and the process stops. It will eventually terminate because the degrees of the $r_i$ are strictly decreasing.

Then $$\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}=d_1(x)+\dfrac1{d_2(x)+\dfrac1{ \ddots+\frac1{d_n(x)}}}$$

This really is the same process as for rational numbers:

$$\begin{align}\frac{12}{5}&=2+\frac{2}{5}\\
&=2+\dfrac1{\frac{5}{2}}\\
&=2+\dfrac1{2+\frac12}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Great! It seems so obvious now... Thanks for the explanation.